# Jwt add claims to token in Spring boot

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, jwt, spring-security-oauth2

Hi I have tried to use jwt tokens in spring boot but I faced a problem that adding custom claims into jwt token. I wanna add custom claims such as issuer, audience, exp, sub,...user:{},..
How can I add my object into header and payload sections

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I have solved it with following code:

```
@Bean
    public JwtAccessTokenConverter tokenEnhancer() {
        KeyStoreKeyFactory keyStoreKeyFactory = new KeyStoreKeyFactory(
                new ClassPathResource("jwt.jks"),
                keyStorePassword.toCharArray());
        // For getting user information in getPrincipal()
        DefaultUserAuthenticationConverter duac = new DefaultUserAuthenticationConverter();
        duac.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        DefaultAccessTokenConverter datc = new DefaultAccessTokenConverter();
        datc.setUserTokenConverter(duac);

        JwtAccessTokenConverter converter = new CustomAccessTokenConverter();
        converter.setAccessTokenConverter(datc); // IMPORTANT
        converter.setKeyPair(keyStoreKeyFactory.getKeyPair("jwt"));
        return converter;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I assume you are using spring-security-oauth2. I didn't get the part `How can I add my object into header and payload sections` but You can use a [TokenEnhancer](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/oauth/apidocs/org/springframework/security/oauth2/provider/token/TokenEnhancer.html) as mentioned [in this tutorial](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-oauth-jwt). A sample snippet from that tutorial is present inline below:

```
public class CustomTokenEnhancer implements TokenEnhancer {
    @Override
    public OAuth2AccessToken enhance(
     OAuth2AccessToken accessToken, 
     OAuth2Authentication authentication) {
        Map<String, Object> additionalInfo = new HashMap<>();
        additionalInfo.put("organization", authentication.getName() + randomAlphabetic(4));
        ((DefaultOAuth2AccessToken) accessToken).setAdditionalInformation(additionalInfo);
        return accessToken;
    }
}
```

for getting additional information you can use AuthorizationServerTokenServices

```
tokenServices.getAccessToken(authentication).getAdditionalInformation();
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I will to try use one of these ways.

Comment: You're welcome. If it solves your proble, please accept it as an answer.

Comment: Hi I did it but I got another  problem with Jwt . When I get current user authentication it returns only user name. How I can get whole user information from OAuth2Authentication Jwt

Comment: @NasibullohYandashev, I have updated the answer inline

Comment: This does not add custom claims to JWT Payload or header. It only adds custom json fields to the final json token response

Comment: @ThanosFisherman yep! Do you have a source that would help to actually add custom claims to the JWT Payload instead of the json token response?